# Angularjs Multiple Directives Asking For Transclusion when lazy loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zurb-foundation, angular-foundation

I'm trying to setup a simple angularjs app using [ui.router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad), [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) and [angular-foundation](http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/).

The app is a multi-view app with it's components lazy loaded using [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad).  I have no problem setting up the views and associated controllers.  However, I am having an issue when trying to display a Foundation alert.  When I try to view my alerts (route1), I get empty alerts.  And the stack trace below.

Why is angular applying the alert directive twice?  A plunker is available here: http://goo.gl/lhtD0c

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [alert, alert] asking for transclusion on:        
<div class="alert-box" ng-class="(type || &quot;&quot;)" ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)">
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$compile/multidir?p0=alert&p1=alert&p2=t…lerts%22%20type%3D%22alert.type%22%20close%3D%22closeAlert(%24index)%22%3E
at https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js:78:12
at assertNoDuplicate (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js:6933:15)
at applyDirectivesToNode (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js:6353:13)
at https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js:6858:37
at https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js:8091:11
at wrappedCallback (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js:11546:81)
at wrappedCallback (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js:11546:81)
at https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js:11632:26
at Scope.$eval (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js:12658:28)
at Scope.$digest (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js:12470:31)
```

The body of my index is below:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <a class="button" ui-sref="route1">Route 1</a>
        <a class="button" ui-sref="route2">Route 2</a>
    </div>

    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

The javascript associated with this page is:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad', 'mm.foundation'])

myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

  // For any unmatched url, send to /route2
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/route2')

  $stateProvider
    .state('route1', {
        url: "/route1",
        controller: 'Route1',
        templateUrl: "route1.html",
        resolve: {
            loadCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: 'myapp',
                    files: ['route1.js']
                })
            }]
        }
    })
    .state('route2', {
        url: "/route2",
        templateUrl: "route2.html"
    })
});

$(function() {
    Foundation.global.namespace = '';
    $(document).foundation();
})
```

The problems are associated with route1.  Here is the route1 template.

```
<div ng-controller="Route1">
    Route 1 - {{ message }}

    <br/>

    <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts"
           type="alert.type"
           close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
</div>
```

and finally the route1.js -

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('Route1', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Hello, world!'

    $scope.alerts = [
        { type: 'danger', msg: 'Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.' },
        { type: 'success round', msg: 'Well done! You successfully read this important alert message.' }
    ];

}]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that it's reloading your "myapp" module dependencies.
Just config ocLazyLoad not to reload foundation like this:

```
$ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
    loadedModules: ['mm.foundation']
});
```

It will be something like that:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad', 'mm.foundation'])

myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider){

  // For any unmatched url, send to /route2
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/route2')

  $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
        loadedModules: ['mm.foundation']
    });

  $stateProvider
    .state('route1', {
        url: "/route1",
        controller: 'Route1',
        templateUrl: "route1.html",
        resolve: {
            loadCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: 'myapp',
                    files: ['route1.js']
                })
            }]
        }
    })
    .state('route2', {
        url: "/route2",
        templateUrl: "route2.html"
    })
});

$(function() {
    Foundation.global.namespace = '';
    $(document).foundation();
})
```

Comment: Thanks Olivier!  I must have missed loadedModules in the documentation.

Comment: no problem, I should enhance the modules detection to avoid problems like this but it's a complex thing to do :)

Comment: @Olivier Thanks, I waste 2-3 hrs to find the solution, save my day

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code

```
<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts"
           type="alert.type"
           close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
```

by

```
<div ng-repeat="alert in alerts">
  <alert type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't change anything.  You can actually see the ng-repeat / alert code working here -> http://embed.plnkr.co/rRJKPEOrW594iEnkJ0Kj/preview

Comment: I forked your plunk & with my changes the code works well http://plnkr.co/edit/hMWQFdAN6BMt9Nr6EGxk?p=preview

Comment: The alerts should be "styled" in nice colored boxes.  Your plunker has a syntax error in route1.html -> alerttype="alert.type" which should read alert type="alert.type"  The bug is nasty.  I do not understand why the alert directive is being gathered twice.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to make this work.  The problem was that ocLazyLoad was reloading the 'myapp' module.  This caused the dependencies to reload.  One of the dependencies was mm.foundation which reprocessed all the directives creating a clone of each pair.

To prevent this,I did not tie the second controller to myapp.  Instead I created a new app 'route1app'.  You can see the updated plunker here:  http://goo.gl/lhtD0c